# The Less is wrong with syntax unit

Tags: less

I have the following LESS:

```
padding-left: unit(@padding-min*@per + 25)px;
@padding-min*@per = 14vw
```

It's compiling to `padding-left: 39 px`.

How can I remove the space between `39` and `px`?

Comment: "`padding-left: unit(@padding-min*@per + 25)px;`" - read the documentation [again](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit).

Comment: thank you! the russian documentation is not enough clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`unit()` function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit) takes the unit as the second parameter.

```
padding-left: unit(@padding-min*@per + 25)px
//                                       ^^^
```

should be

```
padding-left: unit(@padding-min*@per + 25, px);
//                                       ^^^^^
```